# Ninetailed fox not rigging right

Tags: rigging

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRIzqThNP6TcWs0WnlIdmw0Z0V5Z1Y4LXlrYVRHbEc5blVF/view?usp=drivesdk

Please let me know what's going on with it.

Comment: Please don't make the question depend exclusively on users downloading your file and reverse-engineer it. Add a proper description of the problem as text and add images and descriptions of your scene and models, so that others can help you better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really a personalized 
support  request, not a real question. Please read number 9 of [What questions should be definitely off-topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic)

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 1):

- Your meshes are super-messy, you have a lot of vertices overlaying, so you should make some <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* (or <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > merge *By Distance* in 2.8), and play with the *Merge Distance*, but it may merge some vertices that you don't want to merge, so be careful.
- Before parenting your meshes to your armature, you need to bring back the bones to their rest pose: Select them all in *Pose* mode, press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. Now you can see that your tail meshes are not aligned with their bones, you need to align them, or you can do the opposite: in *Edit* mode, align the bones with the meshes.